# ActiveMQ as a service start errors

Tags: windows-services, jms, activemq-classic

I installed ActiveMQ as a service on a Windows 2008 64bit server using commons-deamon.

When I try to start the service I get this error:

```
ACTIVEMQ_HOME: C:\apache-activemq-5.7.0
ACTIVEMQ_BASE: C:\apache-activemq-5.7.0
ACTIVEMQ_CONF: C:\apache-activemq-5.7.0\conf
ACTIVEMQ_DATA: C:\apache-activemq-5.7.0\data
Loading message broker from: xbean:activemq.xml
INFO | Refreshing org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerFactory$1@17494c8: startup date   [Wed Jan 09 16:45:52 IST 2013]; root of context hierarchy
ERROR | Failed to load: class path resource [activemq.xml], reason: Could not load    properties; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: ${activemq.conf}\credentials.properties (The system cannot find the path specified)
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanInitializationException: Could not load   properties; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: ${activemq.conf} \credentials.properties (The system cannot find the path specified)
```

It's like it can't find the file

> ACTIVEMQ_HOME\conf\credentials.properties

but the file does exist in my folder.

Do I need to manually define environment variables or something of that sort?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some files that are missing in the v5.7.0 archive.  You can simply copy them over from the older versions. See: [Jira issue for this problem](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AMQ-4098)